# Why isn't "ls $(pwd/cat)" working?

Tags: linux, ls

in my Ubuntu,for example:

```
$ pwd
/home/yangxiaoyu/c/test
```

If I say:

```
ls /home/yangxiaoyu/c/test/cat
```

I get:

```
ls: 无法访问'/home/yangxiaoyu/c/test/cat': No such file or directory
```

but, if I say:

```
ls $(pwd/cat)
```

I get:

```
bash: pwd/cat: No such file or directory
0x2b    1.txt  catfile  ff    readFile.c  ~rootfile  yxy.h
0X2b.c  a.out  example  list  ref.c       thread.c
```

As you can see, when I use `$(pwd/cat)` as an argument to `ls` it shows an error output and also the list of items in the current directory.

Why is this happening?

Comment: In your 'example', what's cat ?

Comment: I *think* you want `ls $(pwd)/cat`.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `ls <argument>` the command `ls` is executed with a given argument.

When you say `ls $(something)`, that `$(something)` gets evaluated before. And that's the problem you are facing: `pwd/cat` is an invalid command:

```
$ pwd/cat
bash: pwd/cat: No such file or directory
```

So `ls` in `ls $(pwd/cat)` ends up not getting any argument and performs a basic `ls` on the current dir. And it also displays the error for the invalid `pwd/cat` command.

If you want to perform `ls` to an item `cat/` within `pwd`, say:

```
ls "$(pwd)"/cat

ls $PWD/cat
```

or, since the current directory is the default, just:

```
ls cat
```